# arduino yun and rfid shield compatibility

Tags: arduino, rfid, arduino-yun, pn532

I bought an arduino yun together with this board

https://wiki.keyestudio.com/Ks0259_keyestudio_PN532_NFC/RFID_Controller_Shield

reading some posts it seems that they are not compatible because of pinout (with uno no problem!),

I have just small experience with electronics,  but I wander if there is a way to make it work without cabling it?

Comment: I2C should work

Answer (score 0):

as @jurai suggested using it i2c work